# How to create a hyperlink text message for posting on facebook wall in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hiii,I need to post a message on facebook wall with hyperlink included in the message.I tried the following code

```
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
             parameters.putString("message",message);
             parameters.putString("attachment", "{\"name\":\""+"seriesname"+"\","
  +"\"href\":\""+"http://www.google.com\","+"\"description\":\""+"sampledescriptinnn"+"\"}");  
   parameters.putString("description","Testing....."); 
   response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");
```

I am able to post the message on wall but hyperlink is never displayed.Can anyone tell me what is correct way to achieve this.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example from the PHP SDK that you can find [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) in the third example box titled "Post a link to a User's wall using the Graph API".

They call

```
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                array(
                                  'link' => 'www.example.com',
                                  'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                             ));
```

So I would suggest following the same format and have a `Bundle` that contains a "link" with the URL and a "message" with the message you want to put as the description e.g.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("link", "www.google.com");
params.putString("message", Testing.....");
response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
```

Please try that and let us know if you still have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
parameters.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");
```

This will help you.

Comment: Hii Adnan Zahid link key will not display as hyperlink  text in the message.I tried this,I need something like (http://google.com)